# Is there a way not to install tensorflow or keras each time we restart RStudio?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio

When I want to use `keras` and `tensorflow` in R, I use the following codes in order to be able to install them:

```
library(keras) 
library(tensorflow) 
library(reticulate)
```

and it is performing without any problem. The next step is to use the following codes:

```
path_to_python <- "C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310" 
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = path_to_python) 
install_tensorflow(envname = "r-reticulate") 
install_keras(envname = "r-reticulate")
```

Each time I install `keras` and `tensorflow` using `install_keras()` and `install_tensorflow()` functions, I have to re-install them after closing RStudio. I there a way to just load the packages into RStudio Environment?

Comment: I used `reticulate::import_from_path('tensorflow',path_to_python)` and it worked. Is it the right way?

Answer (score 2):

You only have to install each time because you overwrite your python env each time you run this line:

```
virtualenv_create("r-reticulate", python = path_to_python)
```

This overwrites your env as the function name suggests!

instead use:

```
reticulate::use_python( python = path_to_python)
reticulate::use_virtualenv("r-reticulate")
```

to reenter the environment.